# What does "if ($line =~ m/($rr)(.+>)(\d.\d+)" mean?

Tags: string, perl

I am looking through a script that a former employee wrote, and came across this. I am very confused as to what it means. It is a condition of an if loop that runs through a file, and I know what the $rr variable is but everything after that I have no idea what it means... obviously googling "\d" returns nothing pertinent... what is the ".+>" mean too?

```
if ($line =~ m/($rr)(.+>)(\d.\d+)</) {
```

Comment: looks like perl. The =~ operator is in Perl . It binds a match expression  to a scalar expression.

Comment: the \d is any digits ( 0, 1, 2,..  9)  , so \d.\d+ is for matching some decimal numbers

Answer (score 8):

I have used the [`x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) modifier to make the pattern descriptive:

```
$line =~ m/
    ( $rr  )     # Match and capture the value of $rr
    ( .+ > )     # Match and capture everything till the last >
    (            # Capture the following matches
        \d       # Match a single digit
        .        # Match any character a single time
        \d+      # Match one or more digits
    )
/x;
```

There are three captures in the above pattern. These captures can be accessed using the special variables `$1`, `$2` and `$3`.

### References

- [Perl regular expressions tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)
- [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: `(.+)` wouldn't capture anything if there was nothing between the value of `$rr` and the last '>'. Also, you forgot the '<' after `\d+` at the end ;)

Comment: `(.+)` indeed does capture *one or more characters* (or the whole match fails). The `\d+` at the last was not forgotten. It was edited into the question after I answered (and that was not by the owner of the question). :-)

Comment: You totally misread what I said ;) I meant: If the last '>' follows right after `$rr`, then `(.+)` would neither match nor capture anything because it requires at least one character. `(.*)` would make more sense here. But that's not your fault, since OP posted the regex. And I didn't mean the `\d+` at the end, but the '<' that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

This is about regular expressions.

```
if ($line =~ m/($rr)(.+>)(\d.\d+)
```

`$line` is a variable.
The `=~` means does it match this pattern?
The pattern follows.  It's something like `m/` then the variable `$rr`, then `.` (a single character), `+` (matches previous character multiple times).  The `>` I'm not sure.  The `\d` means a digit (i.e. 0 through 9).

Reads up on pattern matching and regular expressions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Regular expressions are similar in many languages such as Perl, Ruby, etc.

Check out most of your string here (ruby): http://rubular.com/r/OTe4jFN545

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for that. The website I am trying to parse is: "http://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=AUD&amount=1.00" basically I am trying to get the exchange rate for a variety of different currencies... just not quite sure how to go about that pattern matching thing

Answer (score 0):

If line matches the regular expression starting with $rr variable followed by atleast one of any character followed by atleast two digit.

how ever im not sure but it seams a paranthesis is missing.

I would try to go here to match the regex

http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml

the regex is m/($rr)(.+>)(\d.\d+ but this seams wrong /($rr)(.+>)(\d.\d+)/ seams better.
the regex also has capture groups that can be accessed within the if statement with

```
$_[0] .. $_[2]
```

Comment: Beware, PHP's regex don't work the same as Perl's, these online regex testing tools are treacherous if you come to rely on them. It doesn't matter for this example, though.

Comment: Oh that was a PHP one.. sry for that I was looknig for a perl one should be more careful.